# FormType Validation symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony

Can you help me plz i can't find the solution

```
<?php

/**
* Description of ContactType
*
* @author Thamer
*/

namespace Common\ContactBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;

class ContactType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'constraints' => array(
                    new Length(array('min' => 3)),
                    new NotBlank()
                )
            )
        )
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
                new NotBlank()
            )
        )
        ->add('tel', 'number', array(
                'constraints' => array(
                    new Length(array('min' => 8)),
                    new NotBlank()
                )
            )
        )
        ->add('message', 'textarea', array(
                'constraints' => array(
                    new Length(array('min' => 10)),
                    new NotBlank()
                )
            )
        )
        ->add('recaptcha', 'ewz_recaptcha')
    ;
}

public function getName() {
    return 'common_contact';
}

}
```

the error is :

> The option "0" does not exist. Defined options are: "action",
>   "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name",
>   "by_reference", "cascade_validation", "compound", "constraints",
>   "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_provider",
>   "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class",
>   "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping",
>   "extra_fields_message", "inherit_data", "intention",
>   "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label",
>   "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "max_length", "method",
>   "pattern", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "read_only",
>   "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "validation_groups",
>   "virtual". 500 Internal Server Error - UndefinedOptionsException

Comment: It often happens when setting an unaccepted key in `$options` parameter. Did you do something with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your lines:

```
->add('email', 'email', array(
            new NotBlank()
        )
    )
```

You are passing in `new NotBlank()`, but it should be in a constraints option:

```
->add('email', 'email', array(
         'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank()
          )
       )
    )
```